# have an issue with Illumination formula which is not clear

Tags: image-processing

[enter link description here](https://projet.liris.cnrs.fr/imagine/pub/proceedings/ICPR-2012/media/files/0454.pdf)Iam trying to understand the Illumination formula bellow which is found in the paper :

```
 Quality Metrics for Practical face Recognition:
```

[image]

Kindly how we calculate Gaussian weight for the regional pixels  W, also  if i have 100 images, can I choose one as reference image ?

Thank you

Comment: did you read the referenced papers? please link the paper you are talking about...

Answer (score 0):

The formulas in the paper do not tell the whole story. They are just quotes from other papers.

From https://projet.liris.cnrs.fr/imagine/pub/proceedings/ICPR-2012/media/files/0454.pdf

> **Illumination**: The illumination of an image can be the estimation of
>   its luminance distortion I1 [14]. Abdel-Mottaleb and Mahoor[1]
>   calculated the illumination as the weighted sum of the mean intensity
>   values of several regions of the image I2.
>
> [1] M. Abdel-Mottaleb and M. Mahoor. Application notes
>   - Algorithms for assessing the quality of facial images. IEEE Comput. Intell. Magazine, 2:10–17, 2007
>
> [14] Z. Wang and A. Bovik. A universal image quality index. IEEE
>   Signal Processing Letters, 9:81–84, 2002

Refer to those papers for further detail.  Based on the provided information you cannot expect more help. Gaussian weights are usually calculated from a sigma and kernel size which is not specified here. The definition of Ii is also not helpful without further information.